# Partial Derivative Calculation Help

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

**Question:** Use the $\newcommand{\p}{\partial}$chain rule to find $\p z/\p s$ when $(s, t) = (1, 2)$ for the equation:
$$z = \arctan(x^2 + y^2)$$
provided that $x = st$ and $y = t^2$.

**My attempted Solution:** For the first step, I converted $\p z/\p s$ into:
$$\frac{{\p z}}{ds} = \frac{{\p z}}{\p x} \cdot\frac{{\p x}}{\p s} + \frac{{\p z}}{\p y} \cdot \frac{{\p y}}{\p s}$$
This would allow me to calculate the partial derivative of each section and put them together. However, I'm not very sure how the calculations are done in this case.

I would be much appreciated if someone could show me how this is done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, all derivatives here are partial derivatives, since we're working with functions of several variables. What you set up for the multivariate Chain Rule is essentially correct, except for the notation. Instead, it must be:
$$\frac{\partial z}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}\cdot\frac{\partial x}{\partial s}+\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}\cdot\frac{\partial y}{\partial s}.$$
Then you just need to calculate the four partial derivative that appear in this expression and put them in there for the final answer. Here are a couple of them:

- $\displaystyle \frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\arctan(x^2+y^2)\right]=\frac{1}{1+(x^2+y^2)^2}\cdot2x=\frac{2x}{1+(x^2+y^2)^2}$, using the "usual" Chain Rule;
- $\displaystyle \frac{\partial x}{\partial s}=\frac{\partial}{\partial s}\left[st\right]=t$;

and similarly you can find the rest.

Comment: It is simple. Write exactly that line which @ziprovich has written.

Comment: What you are asking is something like how would I compute $$\frac{d}{dx}(cx)$$?, which could be described using the simple line.